# Customizing WooCommerce Short Description Metabox title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Can someone guide me by telling me how I can customize/change Text label in Wordpress - I recently installed WooCommerce on my wordpress, and need to change the label "Product Short Description" on the "Add Product" page to something else. Is there a way to getting this done? Please see this image for reference: 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can use [gettext](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext), i have't tested it but i think it can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **To answer to your question:** YES there is a working filter hook that can translate text by the internationalization functions (`__()`,
>   `_e()`, etc.)

Here is this code:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'theme_domain_change_excerpt_label', 10, 2 );
function theme_domain_change_excerpt_label( $translation, $original )
{
    if ( 'Product Short Description' == $original ) {
        return 'My Product label';
    }
    return $translation;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and fully functional.

---

References:

- [gettext](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext)
- [Change The Title Of a Meta Box](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/39446/103815)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [here](https://bryce.se/2012/10/14/change-title-of-wordpress-meta-boxes/)

The basic premise is that you remove the existing metabox and then add it back with a new title, but the same callback, which (as it happens) is similar to what WooCommerce did with the usual "excerpt" metabox. :

```
remove_meta_box( 'METABOX_ID', 'POST_TYPE', 'normal' );
add_meta_box('METABOX_ID', __('META BOX TITLE'), 'METABOX_CALLBACK', 'POST_TYPE', 'normal', 'high');
```

So in this case you'd want to do the following:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'so_39797888_rename_meta_boxes', 40 );
function so_39797888_rename_meta_boxes(){
    remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt', 'product', 'normal' );
    add_meta_box( 'postexcerpt', __( 'This metabox is awesome', 'your-plugin' ), 'WC_Meta_Box_Product_Short_Description::output', 'product', 'normal' );
}
```

You need to be on a priority of 40 so that your function will come *after* WooCommerce has added it's metabox.