# Wordpress change metabox title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, callback, meta-boxes

Actually, I'm working on woocommerce customization...

I've read this question about the title change in metabox:
[Customizing WooCommerce Short Description Metabox title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797888/customizing-woocommerce-short-description-metabox-title)

It help me a lot. But, in the product, how can I find the "metabox tag" callback name?

```
function epptm_rename_meta_boxes(){
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-product_tag', 'product', 'side' );
    add_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-product_tag', __( 'This metabox is awesome', 'your-plugin' ), 'CALLBACK?', 'product', 'side' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'epptm_rename_meta_boxes', 40 );
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution found:

```
/**
 * hook to the 'add_meta_boxes' action to modify title
 */
function change_meta_box_titles() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes; // array of defined meta boxes
    // cycle through the array, change the titles you want
    $wp_meta_boxes['product']['side']['core']['tagsdiv-product_tag']['title']= 'Here is my new title';
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'change_meta_box_titles');
```